# Anyway to call CoInitialize() before an initialization list?

Tags: c++, com, constructor, initialization-list

Here is my C++ code of a constructor of ThorDetectorSwitch.cpp file:

```
ThorDetectorSwitch::ThorDetectorSwitch() : _mcSwitch(__uuidof(MCLControlClass))
{
    _A  = WstringToBSTR(L"A"); 
    _B  = WstringToBSTR(L"B");
    _C  = WstringToBSTR(L"C");
    _D  = WstringToBSTR(L"D");

    _deviceDetected = FALSE;
}
```

As you can see, an initialization list, `_mcSwitch(__uuidof(MCLControlClass))`, is used to initialize a COM object (MCLControlClass, which is registered from a COM dll).

I am wondering is there anyway I can call CoInitialize() before this initialization list? Because I am getting exceptions of "CoInitialize() has not been called". Or any other way to avoid this exception?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't have his class call `CoInitialize` before it's constructed.  Instead, call `CoInitialize` before constructing this class.

Comment: You'd better focus on why this constructor runs too early.  Initialization order is an unsolved problem in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I recommend you use [`CoInitializeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `CoInitialize`. Even the MSDN documentation recommends this. Second I recommend that you call `CoInitializeEx` in `main()` and at the start of each additional thread that requires the use of COM objects. There are very good reasons for this. For instance each call to `CoInitializeEx` should have a corresponding call to [`CoUninitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before the thread ends. This ensures the COM library is properly terminated. If you call it from the constructor you also have to manage the number of times the COM library is initialized so the right number of calls to `CoUninitialize` are made. Another issue is when subsequent calls are made to `CoInitializeEx` with a different apartment model it will fail. If this happens and your constructor is checking for errors like it *should* you end up with a failure condition during instantiation. How do you handle an error condition like that in a constructor? By throwing an exception - not a very pleasant thing to have happen.

My final recommendation is to **read the documentation** and do things the right way otherwise you end up scratching your head like have been for the last few days.

Comment: @Captian Thanks very mich for your explanation. I have put the CoInitialize(NULL) in DllMain(), which is in another C++ file from my ThorDetectorSwitch.cpp, somehow it did not work either. It breaks at hr = CoCreateInstance() in comip.h, where hr = 858993460; The wierd thing I don't understand is that my ThorDetectorSwitch.dll, which calls a COM dll, works fine with another application. But in my current application it throws exceptions like "CoInitialize() has not been called". I pretty much added many CoInitialize() at many places.

Comment: It sounds like you are caliing `CoCreateInstance` from a thread that has not called `CoInitialize`. As a simple test call `CoInitialize` when you handle `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` in your DLL's entry point (DllMain).

Comment: The error occurred after I have added CoInitialize(NULL) in DllMain(); I don't understand how I can do this....like call it again?

Comment: I doubt this has much to do with `CoInitialize` at this point. The error value is wrong, it's actually `-858993460` which converts to 0xcccccccc hex which is _not_ a valid HRESULT. In debug mode this is a strong indication of uninitialized memory which means `CoCreateInstance` probable hasn't returned yet (or hasn't even been called). Narrow everything down to a single block of code (i.e. just `main()`) that reproduces the problem and fits in an SO question.

Comment: So that means where I did wrong? I am really confused at this point.

Comment: Forget your current code for a moment. Create a new project and in `main()` call `CoInitialize`, declare `_mcSwitch` as a local variable and initialize it in the same way your constructor does. You may need to copy & paste _some_ of the declarations but that's ok, as long as the code is _small_ and _manageable_. This will give you an isolated environment to trace the problem and will allow you to post a _complete_ example in your question so that it is easier for people on SO to help you. Just try to make it as small as possible.

Comment: I think it is really hard to explain the problem here, and I am confused on how to simplyify my project. I guess I should stop here. I am truly thankful for your help. But which one of your answer I should accept.

Comment: I am trying to read your comment regarding the -858993460 to see if I can extract more. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with those suggesting to leave such init to main() or InitInstance, and the other refinements, yet let me show one solution to the original question.

As calling the function creates responsibility, you start with a RAII wrapper, something like:

```
class ComIniter
{
public:
    ComIniter() { CoInitialize(); } // or use ex, add params, etc
    ~ComIniter() { CoUnInitialize(); } // adjust to match
private:
    ComIniter(const ComIniter&);  // =delete with C++11
    ComIniter& opeartor=(const ComIniter&); // =delete with C++11
};
```

You can drop an instance at start of main(), the thread functions, and/or at namespace scope before your other static object requiring COM.

If you decide against those and want the original idea, in ThorDetectorSwitch add:

```
private: static const char* ComHelper(const char* arg) { static ComIniter c; return arg; }
```

then use it with the init list:

```
ThorDetectorSwitch::ThorDetectorSwitch() : _mcSwitch(ComHelper(__uuidof(MCLControlClass)))
```

adjust the return type if needed. Once again that it is considered a suboptimal solution compared to the others.

Comment: I tried the code that sticking with the original idea, but compiler says c is a undeclared identifier. I assume ComIniter has to be defined some where?

Comment: it's defined in the first block of post... and what line says that?

Comment: I changed to private: static const GUID ComHelper(const GUID arg) {...}, it compiles. But then there is other excptions: at if (*pfbegin !=NULL) (**pfBeigin)(); ++pfBegin; This is in crt0dat.c; I don't even know what that means....

Comment: most likely the loop that calls ctors for your static/global objects. You still have some that calls away to com before ThorDetectorSwitch gets constructed. Unless it's some unrelated problem.

Comment: Yeah I added your code, but same error. Exceptions orrcurred at r = CoCreateInstance() in comip.h, with hr = 858993460

Comment: put a breakpoint on this location, and the one that calls CoInitialize to see which happens before. But as told many times you should NOT use com before main() started, it only calls for trouble.

Comment: I step in, it hits the constrctor, ThorDetectorSwitch(), then it hits the CoInitialize(NULL) in the class ComHelper, then it hits the hr = CoCreateInstance(.....) in comip.h, then it throws exceptions.

Comment: so that proves that this exception is not because missing CoInitialize (btw did you check if that succeeded?), If you can't figure out I suggest to post that as separate question.

Comment: I actually don't think it was the CoInitialize() problem, but people kept tell me it was. I simply have this ThordetectorSwitch.dll that calls a COM dll. I doubt it was the way I called ThorDetectorSwitch.dll was wrong. I simply used Loadlibrary(_T("ThorDetectorSwitch.dll"));